# is there any solution for pygame black screen error?

Tags: pygame

so I am using Pygame .Whenever I run my game the screen does not renders anything and it seems black however for debugging purpose I use print statement and I find out that all functions are working ,so what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Which code do you talk about?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how you coded the program, I cannot be sure of the exact problem that is causing your program to display a black screen. However, I suspect it might be one of the following:

1. Not having a game loop.
2. Not calling pygame.display.update() in your game loop.
3. Not filling the screen with any color, for example, screen.fill(background_color).

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: More useful than I would be able to bring, taking in account that the OP did not show any code at all. :-)  Just that `pygame.display.flip()` can be used in place of "update"

Comment: Also: 4. You're using MacOS and pygame/SDL is notoriously buggy on MacOS